# iOS 16 Lock Screen Photo Shuffle - category Nature not available for photos synchronized from macOS Photos app

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, lockscreen

iOS 16 offers the option to [rotate multiple photos as your Lock Screen wallpaper](https://support.apple.com/en-gu/HT200285). When I set this up on my iPhone 11, a couple of months ago, it offered me the option to select a group of photos, Nature, which was the setup I wanted.

Now I've imported all photos of my Camera Roll / "Recents" album to the Photos app on macOS (I do not have iCloud Photos enabled), synced the relevant albums to my iPhone, and emptied the "Recents" album to avoid duplication. So all the photos are still there, but in a different album.

A few days later, the Photo Shuffle didn't work anymore and the lock screen became black. The Wallpaper section in the Settings app only offers to show a couple of People (strangely enough, only three out of the seven displayed in the Photos app on iOS, and not even the most frequent ones - I've edited them out of the screenshot):

[image]

I know I can manually select all photos I want to see, but that's several hundreds and I'd rather let Apple's AI do that for me. Is there any option (other than importing them back in the Recents album, which is less than ideal)?